# Calculating the difference column wise of two time series dataframe with different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames  `df1`  (mxn) and `df2`  (mx1) as time series and I want to calculate the difference for each column between `df1`  and `df2`  which would look like `df3`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1.2, 0.4, 0.2, -0.4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 3.2, 'nan', 'nan'], 
    '03K W':[-1, -2.3, 0.3, 2.4], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 3.2, 4.2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    'K W':[1, 1.5, 1.2, 0.8]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[0.2, 1.1, 1, 1.2], 
    '02K W':[2.5, 1.7, 'nan', 'nan'], 
    '03K W':[2, 3.8, 0.9, 1.6], 
    '04K W':[0.5, 1.1, 2, 3.4]})
```

Is there an easy way to build a difference column wise?

Comment: You realized that your data are all strings?

Comment: Oh yes... I'll edit that

Comment: if you get the data types right, this should fit in : ``df1.set_index('Date').sub(df2.set_index('Date').squeeze(), axis = 0)``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `Date` as index, and use `.sub` method:

```
df1.set_index('Date').sub(df2.set_index('Date')['K W'], axis='rows')
```

Output:

```
            01K W  02K W  03K W  04K W
Date                                  
2021-01-01    0.2    2.5   -2.0    0.5
2021-01-02   -1.1    1.7   -3.8    1.1
2021-01-03   -1.0    NaN   -0.9    2.0
2021-01-04   -1.2    NaN    1.6    3.4
```

**Note**: you might want to add `astype(float)` after `set_index('Date')` to correct your data type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How would I need to change it to get the difference instead of a subtraction.

Comment: @fjurt chain that with `abs()`.

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to use numeric values, not strings.

It looks like your 'Date' field represents your index. Pandas series can be added/subtracted element-wise based on their shared index so worth calling those out as an index. Then you can simply iterate through your df1 columns to apply df2 to each.

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1.2, 0.4, 0.2, -0.4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 3.2, nan, nan], 
    '03K W':[-1, -2.3, 0.3, 2.4], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 3.2, 4.2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    'K W':[1, 1.5, 1.2, 0.8]})

df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

df3 = df1.copy()

for c in df1.columns:
    df3[c] = df1[c] - df2['K W']
    
df3
```

Yields:

```
            01K W  02K W  03K W  04K W
Date                                  
2021-01-01    0.2    2.5   -2.0    0.5
2021-01-02   -1.1    1.7   -3.8    1.1
2021-01-03   -1.0    NaN   -0.9    2.0
2021-01-04   -1.2    NaN    1.6    3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do:

```
df4 = df1[['01K W', '02K W', '03K W', '04K W']].astype(float).subtract(df2['K W'].astype(float), axis=0).abs().join(df1['Date'])[['Date','01K W', '02K W', '03K W', '04K W']]


print(df4)
```